# Button Linking in ajax table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please look at the ajax code below, As you can see, i have managed to make a button display in each table row, which is great, the issue is each button will only link ti the dataurl, I'm really needing to make it so that each button will link off to a different place, But only is the event is still available. E.g. if  a row disappears i need the button to disappear? So the Increment feature wouldn't work.

Thanks
Sam

Heres the ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'api link for seatwave',
    success: function(json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.results.TicketGroups.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results.TicketGroups[i].TicketTypeName;
            var no = json.results.TicketGroups[i].Qty;
            var price = json.results.TicketGroups[i].
            Price;
            var button =
                "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>seatwave</td><td>" + section +
                "</td><td>N/A</td><td>N/A</td><td>" + no +
                "</td><td>£"+price +
                "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
        sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: please post an example of a post-ajax generated table

Comment: Hard to make much sense of what you are asking. `link to different place`? If row is removed why wouldn't button that is in row also be removed? Also what is the increment issue?

Comment: but if its removed, and autoincrementing is apart of the question, and said row is in the middle of the table, all the incrementing would mess up?

Comment: Where do you want the buttons to link to, where does this information come from, and how is it different for each? What you have should be unique to each button, you simply have to find a way to replace `LINK` with something unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are selecting all buttons every iteration of the for loop;

```
//this line selects all elements with classes .btn.btn-info
$("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info")
```

therefore once its done all your buttons will have the link of the last created button.

it would be easier if instead of the line:

```
var button = "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
```

you would wrap the button with a jQuery object, and attach the click handler to it:

```
var button = $("<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>");
button.click(function() {
     location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
});
```

and when you add the button to the dom you can do it this way:

```
//this will retrieve the html element from the jquery object
"</td><td>" + button[0] + "</td></tr>"
```

Comment: The buttons will not have the link of the last created button. Assuming that his data-url attribute is an actual link, the click event should be unique to each button. Each click event should be accessing the data-url of the individual item that's clicked. Can you post a jsfiddle of what you have in mind because looking at what you have here I don't see how this would work.

Comment: Sorry, ive been in dreamweaver not paying attention to the real world, heres the js fiddle, its something on how i'd like it to work, but obviously the data is auto populated so each link would need to be unique http://jsfiddle.net/4t5h6nxh/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right, but I think you want to set the value of your `data-url='LINK'` attribute.

For example you can set it right away in your String, like so:

```js
var link = isEventAvailable ? json.results.getLink() : undefined;
var button = link ?  "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='" + link + "Click Here</button>" : return "whatever action";
```

So the above checks whether the event is available or not, if so you get the link from wherever you want, if not set it to a falsy value, js often uses `undefined` for this. Now set your button string to button only if link has been set otherwise to whatever you want.

Another route:

```js
var button = "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
button.attributes.getNamedItem("data-url").value = link;
```

This is nasty but verbose enough so that you can check it out in the APIs:
[Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)
[NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)

And then see the Attribute Object